# Visual Studio ругается на ассемблерную вставку

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++, ассемблер

Задание сделать разветвляющую программу на С++. Вроде сделала, а Visual Studio 2022 ругается. В чем проблема?

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int a, b, c, d, e, y;
    cout << "a,b,c,d,e" << endl;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> d >> e;
    _asm {
        mov eax, a
        mov ebx, b
        cmp ebx, eax
        jg m1
        jmp m3

        m3 : mov eax, a // 2 код
        imul b
        idiv c
        add eax, d
        sub eax, e
        jmp m25

        m2 : mov eax, d // 1 код 
        imul e
        mov ebx, eax
        mov eax, b
        idiv c
        add eax, a
        sub eax, ebx
        jmp m25

        m1 : mov ecx, c
        mov edx, d
        cmp ecx, edx
        jle m2

        m25 : mov y, eax
    }
    cout << "Result =" << y << endl;
    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Вот ошибка:
Ошибка  C4235   использовано нестандартное расширение: ключевое слово "__asm" данной архитектурой не поддерживается

Comment: Может, вы компилируете под x64? Там и в самом деле не поддерживается, компилируйте под x86.

Comment: MSVC не поддерживает встроенный ассемблер, на архитектуре x64. (только x86).

Comment: @Harry, компиляция под x86 решит проблему или нужно перейти на устройство x86  и сделать там?

Comment: Просто компилируйте под x86. **Эту** проблему решит. Но я не смотрел ваш код, нет ли там *других* проблем.

Comment: Не используйте ассемблерные вставки. Делайте отдельные единицы трансляции.

Answer (score 1):

Измените здесь х64 на х86, и Ваша проблема должна решиться.

[image: Здесь нужно изменить]

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы.